# perl compare sorted array using smart match

Tags: arrays, perl, sorting

The following is the code, actually, @arr0 and @arr1 are not equal, even after sorting, they are not equal, but why "eq" will be printed? at first, I thought about the return value of sort funtion, but it did return an array,so what's the reason?

```
my @arr0 = (1,2);
my @arr1 = ("a","b");

if ( (sort @arr0) ~~ (sort @arr1) ) {
    print "eq\n";
};
```

Comment: What Perl version are you using? The smartmatch operator has been changed a few times. I don't remember if the use case array and array was affected, but better tell us.

Comment: the Perl version is v5.12.1,thank you.

Comment: With the current 5.24.1 behavior it should do string equal on each pair for arrays. But you have lists, not arrays. That might make a difference. Maybe they get forced into scalar context. I don't have a computer right now. Try to put the arrays directly.

Comment: If put the sorted array to a new array, and use smartmatch to compare the new arrays, it is correct. here is the new test codes.  "eq2" will be printed, "eq1" will not.`my @arr0 = ("a","b");my @arr1 = ("b","a");print "eq1\n" if ( sort @arr0 ~~ sort @arr1 ) ;my @sorted0 = sort @arr0;my @sorted1 = sort @arr1;print "eq2\n" if ( @sorted0 ~~ @sorted1 );` thanks.

Comment: **The smart-matching experimental feature should be avoided because it will be removed or changed in a manner that is not backwards compatible.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Note:** All links to documentation in this answer are to the documentation for version 5.12.1. This ensures the answer is useful for the original poster - it might make it less useful for other people.]

It's important to realise that arrays and lists are not the same. This is one case where the behaviour is different.

It's also important to read the [documentation for `sort()`](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.12.1/functions/sort.html), which starts by saying:

> In list context, this sorts the LIST and returns the sorted list value. In scalar context, the behaviour of sort() is undefined.

There are two important things there. Firstly, in list context, `sort()` returns a list, not an array. And secondly, in scalar context, its behaviour is undefined.

Now let's look at the [smartmatch documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.12.1/perlsyn.html#Smart-matching-in-detail). That's a big table of left- and right-operands that I won't reproduce here. But note that it doesn't mention lists at all. So, almost certainly, smartmatch is calling `sort()` in scalar context and doing either a string or numeric comparison 
on the results (one of the last few rows in the table).

But we know that `sort()`'s behaviour in scalar context is undefined. So who knows what value smartmatch is comparing. But I guess that whatever random value it is returning, it is (at least) returning the same random value for both of your lists. Which means they appear to be equal.

As you've said in a comment, it works when you save the sorted results in arrays and pass arrays to smartmatch. That's because arrays have special behaviours defined in the smartmatch table.

- Arrays are not lists
- Don't call `sort()` in scalar context

**Update:** As [ThisSuitIsNotBlack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/176646/thissuitisblacknot) mentions in the comments, smartmatch has been rather unstable since it was introduced in Perl 5.10. Its behaviour has been tweaked in pretty much every Perl release since then and its final form still isn't completely agreed. For that reason, I strongly discourage you from using it at all.

Comment: I would add a third bullet point: Don't use smartmatch. It's experimental and will definitely change in the future.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: Yes, I meant to mention that. Thanks for the reminder. I've added it to my answer.

Comment: Re "*Its behaviour has been tweaked in pretty much every Perl release since*", That's not true. There's only been two changes: 5.10.1 (functional changes), and 5.18 (marked as experimental).

Comment: There are tweaks mentioned in perldelta for 5.14 and 5.16 as well. They were bug-fixes, but they changed the behaviour of the operator. And, to be honest, I have no problem with a small amount of poetic licence if it steers people away from the smartmatch operator.